# Dedicated NVidia GPU is not running when playing games on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, asus, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime, amd-ryzen

So I've got myself a new ASUS TUF Gaming FX705DT and absolutely want to avoid installing Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu 20.04. Had a minor problem with the Wi-Fi driver, installed steam and War Thunder through it. I ran the game with nouveau and it crashed. So, I had to install an NVidia proprietary driver. Tried  418, 430, 440, 450 and 455. Non of them make the game run on NVidia GPU, the game runs on integrated(giving 10-29 FPS). The first 3 versions (418, 430 and 440) give a blank Nvidia X server settings program. The other 2 (450 and 455) give a short menu with no PRIME. When running `nvidia-settings` the message says PRIME: is it supprted? no.

I have spent more than 10 hours trying to fix this but no luck so far. Can anyone help me, please?

Here are my specs:

```
System:
  Host: ASUS-FX705DT Kernel: 5.4.0-52-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: TUF Gaming FX705DT_FX705DT v: 1.0 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: FX705DT v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: FX705DT.310 date: 12/24/2019 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 64.3 Wh condition: 64.0/64.1 Wh (100%) 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: AMD Ryzen 7 3750H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx 
  bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
  Speed: 1249 MHz min/max: 1400/2300 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1229 2: 1279 
  3: 1252 4: 1250 5: 1225 6: 1227 7: 1225 8: 1224 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] driver: nvidia 
  v: 450.80.02 
  Device-2: AMD Picasso driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: amdgpu,ati,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~120Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-52-generic LLVM 10.0.0) 
  v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-52-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  driver: r8169 
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: d4:5d:64:64:1b:03 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
  driver: rtl8821ce 
  IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: d8:c0:a6:30:5b:c7 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 58.89 GiB (12.3%) 
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Micron model: 2200V MTFDHBA512TCK 
  size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 58.88 GiB (12.6%) fs: ext4 
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 52.1 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 52 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 2400 
Info:
  Processes: 315 Uptime: 11m Memory: 7.65 GiB used: 1.99 GiB (26.0%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

`nvidia-smi` output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   46C    P8     1W /  N/A |     11MiB /  3911MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       837      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1410      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`nvidia-settings` output:

```
(nvidia-settings:6231): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:55:47.314: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

** Message: 23:55:47.367: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 23:55:47.367: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

Comment: I really wish you the best of luck on this, using your Nvidia GPU on ubuntu can be quite challenging. Could you give us the output of `nvidia-smi` ?

Comment: @StatisticDean I couldn't insert the output to this comment so I edited my main post and put it there on the bottom. Please, check.

Comment: Could you edit in the output of nvidia-settings as well ?

Comment: The nvidia-smi output looks like you are runnin on the Nvidia 450 driver, so look in Steam settings for GPU to use, or maybe just reinstall Steam but now with the Nvidia driver in place.

Comment: @StatisticDean Ok, I have added the output. Sorry it took so long.

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes, I am now using ```__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia %command%``` in SET LAUNCH OPTIONS. The video card is used now but only in "Ultra Low" for War Thunder. The  FPS is much higher (70-90) but that's still not good.